# Azure app services - can't invoke API through Android client

Tags: android, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to invoke a simple API through the Android SDK.

I have created an app service and since I'm having some difficulties connecting my Android native app to the service's backend, I have tried a simple test first.

I have created an `Easy API` with the name `test_api1` through the portal, with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        res.status(200).type('text').send("1");
    },
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        res.status(200).type('text').send("2");
    }
};
```

The api has no authentication needed for it (everything is defined `anonymous`).

When I simply invoke it through the browser (by going to `https://*.azurewebsites.net/api/test_api1`) I can see `1` in the browser as expected.

However, when I try to invoke the API through the app I get an error. Here is the code that I use to invoke the API:

```
    private void testAPI() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Running API");
        ListenableFuture<JsonElement> res = this.azureClient.invokeApi("test_api1");
        Futures.addCallback(res, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@Nullable JsonElement result) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
                if (result != null) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, result.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "failure", t);
            }
        });
    }
```

Where `this.azureClient` is initiated by the following way through the `MainActivity`:

```
    private void initAzureConnection(Context context) {
        try {
            azureClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://*.azurewebsites.net",
                    context
            );
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "failed to initialize azure client", ex);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app I get the following error:

```
2019-05-06 19:14:15.959 5414-5414/com.*.* E/MAIN_ACTIVITY: failure
    com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:139)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1611)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:114)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:164)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:122)
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1611) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:114) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:551)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354) 
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:164) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:122) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$15.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:1611) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:114) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:78) 
        at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:35) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a network issue, and this error cannot be solved by the client, since it is a network related issue. However, what you can do is retry connecting a few times. This may work as a workaround until the real issue is fixed.

Sample code:

```
for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; retries++) {
    try {
        final HttpClient client = createHttpClientWithDefaultSocketFactory(null, null);
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("GET Request on '" + get.getURI().toString() + "' resulted in " + statusCode);
        } else {                
            return response.getEntity();
        }
    } catch (final java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // connection timed out...let's try again                
    }
}
```

One way to effectively handle it is to define a connection timeout and later handle it by using a `try catch` block.... hope this will help anyone in future who are facing the same issue.

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000); //set the timeout in milliseconds
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Since indeed the mobile backend gave me many problems, I turned to use the azure HTTP function in order to connect to our database and backend